# Is possible make subdomains with wildcards without redirect (R flag)?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard

I think that I have configured ok the wildcards in my domain, because it works to me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/member.php?username=%1 [R,L]
```

But only if I redirect with R or R=301 flag. I would like to have a virtual subdomain, and the user don't notice it. subdomain.example.com and don't change the url in the bar.

I have tried the next:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/member.php?username=%1 [L]
```

Without the R flag. But I get an Internal Server Error. What is the problem? Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect to a absolute url without redirect.

"Virtual user host" section in this [document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#content) solves your problem.

If you user.example.com and www.example.com are pointing to same machine then

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).example.com 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$      /member.php?username=%1 [L]
```

But what are you planning to do with group captured in RewriteRule

Comment: You are right, but the URL is also renamed and the user can see the change. I only want urls more easies for the users. I dont want that user see the change nick.example.com to www.example.com/member.php?username=nick

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment after write it. Is the above. The internal server is gone you are right. But with my code the url doesnt change, with yours work but the url change. Do you know how I can do for the redirection without the change in the url?

Comment: enable rewrite log and see whats happening,  RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log" RewriteLogLevel 9

Comment: Can you try to move the condition to <VirtualHost> context from .htaccess

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand your last message. About the RewriteLog I have tried it in .htaccess and only for that I get an internal error. Maybe I have to paste that in other site.

Comment: Can u give the RewriteLog path to the same directory as access logs or error logs?.

Comment: Yes I can, you was talking to add that in httpd.include. I have done, but result that after make changes in .htaccess the rewrite that luch the internal error work. And happen the same, the url is changing. Is there a way that it doesn`t change? Without R the URL must no cheange

Comment: Will be able to check whats happening if I get the RewriteLogs or whole config of your apache server. Rewrite is not trivial, lots of special cases.

Comment: It works! You are right, my code was wrong your code is the right. With my code i have internal error. Yesterday I read again the config of my vhost and I replaced the line ServerAlias example.com -> ServerAlias  www.example.com *.example.com And work all ok after restart the server. Really thank you. I tried lot of codes some months ago.